# How to mock psycopg2 cursor object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, psycopg2

I have this code segment in Python2:

```
def super_cool_method():
    con = psycopg2.connect(**connection_stuff)
    cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
    cur.execute("Super duper SQL query")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        # do some data manipulation on row
    return rows
```

that I'd like to write some unittests for. I'm wondering how to use `mock.patch` in order to patch out the cursor and connection variables so that they return a fake set of data? I've tried the following segment of code for my unittests but to no avail:

```
@mock.patch("psycopg2.connect")
@mock.patch("psycopg2.extensions.cursor.fetchall")
def test_super_awesome_stuff(self, a, b):
    testing = super_cool_method()
```

But I seem to get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the cursor is the return value of `con.cursor`, you only need to mock the connection, then configure it properly. For example,

```
query_result = [("field1a", "field2a"), ("field1b", "field2b")]
with mock.patch('psycopg2.connect') as mock_connect:
    mock_connect.cursor.return_value.fetchall.return_value = query_result
    super_cool_method()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The result I get from fetchall is '<MagicMock name='connect().cursor().fetchall()' id='40430416'>'

Comment: @AllenLin That's because I didn't configure a return value for `fetchall`, just `execute`.

Comment: cursor.execute usually returns None. Why would you configure a return value for execute but not fetchall?

Comment: Because clearly I *should* have mocked `fetchall` :) Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working for me. I've posted my problem as it's own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164891/cant-mock-cursor-fetchone-return-value-python

Comment: @chepner: actually, because both `connect` and `execute` are **called**, you need to inject a few more `return_value` references here. Not that the return value of `execute` is used though, `fetchall` is never referenced on that mock.

Comment: Correct line is `mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.return_value.fetch_all.return_value = query_result`

Comment: For future reference, this doesn't work because he mistyped `fetch_all`, when he should have write `fetchall`. Changing to that it woks.

Comment: Correct line is actually `mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value.fetch_all.return_value = query_result` - `fetchall` is not a member of `execute`

Comment: I think it's fixed now. `fetchall` is, indeed, not a method of the return value of `execute`; rather `execute` prepares a cursor for using `fetchall`.

Answer (score 66):

You have a series of chained calls, each returning a new object. If you mock *just* the `psycopg2.connect()` call, you can follow that chain of calls (each producing mock objects) via `.return_value` attributes, which reference the returned mock for such calls:

```
@mock.patch("psycopg2.connect")
def test_super_awesome_stuff(self, mock_connect):
    expected = [['fake', 'row', 1], ['fake', 'row', 2]]

    mock_con = mock_connect.return_value  # result of psycopg2.connect(**connection_stuff)
    mock_cur = mock_con.cursor.return_value  # result of con.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
    mock_cur.fetchall.return_value = expected  # return this when calling cur.fetchall()

    result = super_cool_method()
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

Because you hold onto references for the mock `connect` function, as well as the mock connection and cursor objects you can then also assert if they were called correctly:

```
mock_connect.assert_called_with(**connection_stuff)
mock_con.cursor.asset_called_with(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
mock_cur.execute.assert_called_with("Super duper SQL query")
```

If you don't need to test these, you could just chain up the `return_value` references to go straight to the result of `cursor()` call on the connection object:

```
@mock.patch("psycopg2.connect")
def test_super_awesome_stuff(self, mock_connect):
    expected = [['fake', 'row', 1], ['fake', 'row' 2]]
    mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value.fetchall.return_value = expected

    result = super_cool_method()
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

Note that if you are using the connection as a [*context manager* to automatically commit the transaction](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement) *and* you use `as` to bind the object returned by `__enter__()` to a new name (so `with psycopg2.connect(...) as conn: # ...`) then you'll need to inject an additional `__enter__.return_value` in the call chain:

```
mock_con_cm = mock_connect.return_value  # result of psycopg2.connect(**connection_stuff)
mock_con = mock_con_cm.__enter__.return_value  # object assigned to con in with ... as con    
mock_cur = mock_con.cursor.return_value  # result of con.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
mock_cur.fetchall.return_value = expected  # return this when calling cur.fetchall()
```

The same applies to the result of `with conn.cursor() as cursor:`, the `conn.cursor.return_value.__enter__.return_value` object is assigned to the `as` target.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the context manager `__enter__` advice. From a philosophy perspective, is this a suggested way of testing? it seems like it is just comparing `expected` to `expected` as returned from the mock, so this test would always work even if the logic in `super_cool_method()` changed - as long as the syntax is valid the test would never break. Is this a simple example to illustrate the point, or is it doing something I've missed? I can see that you can enforce `DictCursor` which is valuable, but can't see why `fetchall.return_value` is being tested, trying to learn.

Comment: @Davos yes, this is a good philosophy because your unit test should not be testing if psycopg2 is working correctly, it should be testing if your code is using the results correctly. Real-world code under test will do something with the result from `fetchall()` and it is that something that matters. Or you want to test what was passed to cursor.execute(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
@patch("psycopg2.connect")
async def test_update_task_after_launch(fake_connection):
    """
    
    """
    fake_update_count =4
    fake_connection.return_value = Mock(cursor=lambda : Mock(execute=lambda x,y :"",  
fetch_all=lambda:['some','fake','rows'],rowcount=fake_update_count,close=lambda:""))
```

Comment: more detailed answer:


    connection_mock.return_value = Mock(
        __enter__=lambda dsn: Mock(
            cursor=lambda: Mock(
                __enter__=lambda cursor_factory: Mock(
                    __enter__=lambda: "",
                    execute=lambda query_str, args: "",
                    fetchone=lambda: [0],
                ),
                __exit__=lambda arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4: "",
            ),
        ),
        __exit__=lambda arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4: "",
    )

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is the variation of above answers. 
I was using `django.db.connections` cursor object.

So following code worked for me

```
@patch('django.db.connections')
def test_supercool_method(self, mock_connections):
    query_result = [("field1a", "field2a"), ("field1b", "field2b")]
    mock_connections.__getitem__.return_value.cursor.return_value.__enter__.return_value.fetchall.return_value = query_result

    result = supercool_method()
    self.assertIsInstance(result, list)
```