# Mocking postgressql using python & pytest

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, pytest, pymock

```
def fetch_holidays_in_date_range(src):
    query = "SELECT * from holiday_tab where id = src"
    db = dbconnect.connect()
    # defining the cursor for reading data
    cursor = db.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    # query the database
    cursor.execute(query.format(src));
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    dbconnect.destroy(cursor, db)
    return rows
```

Could someone help, how to mock this code in pytest or in unittest. I've googled for mock db and I hardly found anything.

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143055/how-to-mock-psycopg2-cursor-object) (how to mock postgresql cursor) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Pytest doesn't support you to run the test on production/main DB if you are using pytest-django. 
There is a better approach to solve this issue.

- [Pytest DB resolve method](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html)
- This says that whenever you run the test with a marker `@pytest.mark.django_db`, tests are run on another newly created db with name `test_your production_db_name`.
- So if your db name is `hello`, pytest will create a new db called `test_hello` and runs tests on it